# Add Variable inside th:onsubmit thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add variable inside th:onsubmit with

```
th:onsubmit="return confirm('Hi '" + ${user.name} +  "')"
```

but it always get me error like

> Malformed markup: Attribute "+" appears more than once in element

also i can't find onsubmit example on thymeleaf official document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about `onsubmit` which is why there is nothing in the official documentation about it -- you're simply not formatting the expression correctly.  I would format the expressions like this:

```
th:data-username="${user.name}"
onsubmit="return confirm('Hi ' + this.getAttribute('data-username'))"
```

(To avoid security errors, Thymeleaf may prohibit you from concatenating strings directly in your JavaScript, which is why I'm separating it out to it's own attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in your `onsubmit` event, and assign the Thymeleaf expression to a variable within that function.

Example (using `onclick` in my case):

```
<yourtag ... onclick="runMyFunction();"></yourtag>

...

<script th:inline="javascript">
    function runMyFunction() {
        var user_name = [[${user.name}]];
        console.log(user_name);
    }
</script>
```

This uses Thymeleaf's [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) syntax `[[${...}]]`.

Note that in this case, the event does not have to be `th:onsubmit` - just `onsubmit`.