# Pass Thymleaf variable to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to pass Thymleaf variable to a javascript function. My Thymleaf portion is like this

```
<a class="cat-title"  th:onclick="|fetchProduct('${category.categoryId}','${businessId}')|">
                                    <p th:text="${category.name}"></a>
```

And my javascript code is like this

```
   function fetchProduct(businessId,categoryId) {

    var productUrl = '/webstore/business/' + businessId + '/category/' + categoryId + '/products';
    ............
    ............
    }
```

But when I load the page I get this error

> Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Only
>   variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this
>   context, any other datatypes are not trusted in the context of this
>   expression, including Strings or any other object that could be
>   rendered as a text literal.

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Variable inside th:onsubmit thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596767/add-variable-inside-thonsubmit-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<a class="cat-title"  th:onclick="fetchProduct([[${category.categoryId}]], [[${businessId}]]);">
    <p th:text="${category.name}"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason might be this bug https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/707 reported some time ago.

You can try inlining JS vars:

```
<a class="cat-title" 
   th:onclick="'javascript:fetchProduct(\'' + [[${category.categoryId}]] + '\', \'' + [[${businessId}]] + '\');'">
       <p th:text="${category.name}">
</a>
```

There is also another approach that should also work (haven't checked it in editor!) but it looks a bit better as you don't need to concat strings and so many \' :)

```
<a class="cat-title" 
    th:dataCatId="${category.categoryId}"
    th:dataBizId="${businessId}" 
    th:onclick="javascript:fetchProduct(this.getAttribute('dataCatId'), this.getAttribute('dataBizId'));">
        <p th:text="${category.name}">
</a>
```

Comment: what does "this.getAttribute('dataCatId')" mean?

Comment: @user3692033 `this` in that context refers to your HTML element `a` and `getAttribute()` method is how you can get some attribute's value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute. I believe Thymeleaf shout generate plain HTML <a ...></a> with 2 custom attributes and they will be accessible via `getAttribute()` method, so you don't need to inline JS stuff and concat strings, etc.