# Thymeleaf onclick href with variable

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot with Thymeleaf project and I'm having trouble writing a button's onclick. I want the resulting url to be e.g. `/owners/1/edit`. I've tried a number of concatenations the latest being:

```
th:onclick="'window.location.href=\'/owners/{id}/edit(id=${owner.id})\''"
```

...but it doesn't evaluate properly, displaying only `/owners/{id}/edit(id=${owner.id})`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a modified version of your approach, without needing a button. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602421/12567365) for an example. So, in your case that would be something like this: `<div th:data-ownerid="@{/owners/{id}/edit(id=${owner_id})}" onclick="window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-ownerid');">click me!</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<a>` tag instead of `onClick`. 
Your code will look something like this -

```
    <a th:href="@{/owners/{id}/edit(id=${owner.id})}"> 
         <button type="button"> some button text </button> 
    </a>
```

Comment: Sonar gives me an error stating illegal position of anchor tag (inside button). An anchor link would work but I'm using buttons everywhere else :(

Comment: If you want to use button, simple put the button inside the <a> tag. I've edited my answer, check if it is working out for you.

Comment: It works! I didn't know you could do that and sonar is happy. Thanks a lot.